# where is 'refresh sequencer' in the VSE of 2.8?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I insert a scene from the 3d view into the VSE, and as expected it has specific frames where its displaying pure grey or just plain wrongly. 2.79 had a big fat "refresh sequencer" button, which you normally pound to fix this problem. I can't find anything of the sort under any of the tabs I find in the vse viewports. Where is it? And if it's not there how am I supposed to refresh the strips so I see the right thing? the control+r thing or whatever the hotkey for "refresh strip" never had anything to do with fixing this problem in 2.79 and it doesn't here either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find it in the View menu:
[image]